# How to track whether user is online in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing my final year project a chatting similar to WhatsApp. Please help me.

I want to track the user whether the app is in the foreground or not?

I had used the firebase database to store data.

I have used this function given below in all activities ie. in onStart updated as online and in onDestory and onStop updated as offline.

```
 public static void currentState(String state) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String currentDate, currentTime;
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    currentDate = sdfDate.format(calendar.getTime());
    currentTime = sdfTime.format(calendar.getTime());
    Map<String, Object> stateMap = new HashMap<>();
    stateMap.put("date", currentDate);
    stateMap.put("time", currentTime);
    stateMap.put("state", state);
    try {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(currentUserid).updateChildren(stateMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isComplete()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: status updated");
                }
            }
        });
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But this approach is not working since I am using fragments some time it is not updating offline and also I am adding in each fragment too while switching activity it updates offline and online rapidly it looks ugly. Is there any way to track users' foreground state?

can anyone help to complete my project successfully

Comment: On pause Method gonna tell you when your app lost focus.

Comment: @TeddySmith losing whenever an activity is navigated and returning back to the fragment. My Home page is consist of 4 fragments.